# How to format a date specifically

Tags: reactjs, datetime, datepicker, material-ui, date-formatting

`"2021-05-12T22:25:37.653Z"`

Is the date object that I currently create when selecting hours for a work week. You have a start-time and an end-time. Both of these are selected from the Mui KeyBoardPicker component.

I need to be able to get just the hours and minutes in local time to show up. It seems that this format isn't recognized as a date because before I used this function `toLocaleTimeString([],TIME_STRING_FORMAT)`
and my time format was below. I'm not sure if this problem is occuring because of the time picker or because of how I'm trying to format the date itself. Any help would be appreciated

```
const TIME_STRING_FORMAT = {
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) to format this time. Actually, I was also having a problem formatting this type of Material-Ui time.
If you only need an hour and a minute then you can do this using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

```
moment("2021-05-12T22:25:37.653Z").format('hh:mm')
```

or for full time with year to the minute

```
moment("2021-05-12T22:25:37.653Z").format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A')
```

hope this would help you. Please check the documentation of [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) that would help you do it more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Reading [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString), you have to do something like:

```js
let date = new Date("2021-05-12T22:25:37.653Z");
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }));
```

And the result is the format you need (2 digit for hours and minutes).